# How to make a server-side HTML template?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, express, pug

I want to use create a layout for all of my pages with the help of Bootstrap. I already have the layout for a single page, but I want to use the same layout for every page. I was thinking that I could use Jade to do this, but I want to make sure that's the right way.

Should I basically just write everything with Jade and not write any HTML? Then I could easily use Jade's features such as 'extend'. Is that the way of the road?

Since I'm new at this, I want to double-check with some people before putting in all that effort. So what is the typical way of sharing an HTML layout across multiple pages?

Edit: I'm planning to use Node and Express since I'm most familiar with them.

Comment: Which techno do you want in server side ? JS ?

Comment: I'm going with JS since I've used Node and Express before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends which server framework you'll use, but typically you'd create a layout template in Jade and each page would be a separate template that uses that layout. The layout would have general Bootstrap structure with the right rows, columns, etc. as well as general HTML container stuff (head tag, showing a title etc, and a footer); and the pages could use any Bootstrap component.